# Building a rolling mean forecast

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, rollapply, rolling-computation

I have a series of intermittent demand called parts (sample below) and I want to develop a rolling mean forecast of a training set and a test set.  My code is below as well. the series fitmean calculates the rolling mean, but there are two problems:

1. It adds a 13th element when all I really want is to get a rolling mean of 12; and,
2. The dates go from Jun 2016 to Jun 2017, so when I subtract testparts I only get the 6 values for Jan to Jun 2017.

Is there a way to (1) remove the 13th element at the end of fitmean, and (2) change the dates so they match with testparts?

Thank you.

```
library(forecast,zoo)
parts<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,7,0,0),nrow=24,ncol=1)
parts<-ts(parts,f=12,start=c(2016,1))
maemean<-matrix(NA,nrow=12,ncol=1)
  trainparts<-window(parts,end=c(2016,12))
  testparts<-window(parts,start=c(2017,1),end=c(2017,12))
  fitmean<-round(rollapply(parts, width=12, by = 1, FUN = mean))
  maemean<-abs(fitmean-testparts)

Jan-16  0
Feb-16  0
Mar-16  0
Apr-16  0
May-16  0
Jun-16  0
Jul-16  2
Aug-16  0
Sep-16  0
Oct-16  0
Nov-16  0
Dec-16  0
Jan-17  3
Feb-17  0
Mar-17  0
Apr-17  0
May-17  0
Jun-17  0
Jul-17  1
Aug-17  0
Sep-17  0
Oct-17  7
Nov-17  0
Dec-17  0
```

Clarification:

The above list should break down to a training set from Jan-16 to Dec-16 and a test set from Jan-17 to Dec-17.  What I want to do is use a rolling mean so the average of Jan-16 to Dec-16 (rounded, which is 0) becomes the forecast for Jan-17, and so on, i.e., Feb-16 to Jan-17, etc.   The output should look like this

```
Jan-17  0
Feb-17  0
Mar-17  0
Apr-17  0
May-17  0
Jun-17  0
Jul-17  0
Aug-17  0
Sep-17  0
Oct-17  0
Nov-17  1
Dec-17  1
```

Unfortunately, I get this with 13 vice 12 elements.

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2016                       0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2017   0   0   0   1   1   1
```

Comment: My biggest issue, and I don't know how to fix it, is that this is a rolling mean forecast to compare with the period Jan-17 to Dec-17 which I want to use to caluculate MAE and MASE.  But when I use rollapply, it keeps the dates Jan-16 to Dec-16, so I can't calulate an MAE.

Comment: Understood.  The above list should break down to a training set from Jan-16 to Dec-16 and a test set from Jan-17 to Dec-17.  What I want to do is use a rolling mean so the average of Jan-16 and Feb-16 (which is 0) becomes the forecast for Jan-17, and so on.  The out put should look likeJan-17 0
Feb-17 0
Mar-17 0
Apr-17 0
May-17 0
Jun-17 0
Jul-17 0
Aug-17 0
Sep-17 0
Oct-17 0
Nov-17 1
Dec-17 1

Comment: Done, please see question ... and thanks!

Comment: I apologize.  I'm kind of new to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) width = list(...)** Removing all the irrelevant code from the question and changing the `rollapply` line we have this where `-seq(12)` is a vector of offsets instructing `rollapply` to pass the first prior, second prior, ... twelfth prior values to mean at each point.

```
library(zoo)

# test data
parts <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0), 
  nrow = 24, ncol = 1)
parts <- ts(parts, freq = 12, start = c(2016, 1))

round(rollapply(parts, list(-seq(12)), FUN = mean))
```

giving:

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2017   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

**2) rollsumr** Another approach would be to take a rolling sum of width 13 and then subtract off the current value and divide by 12:

```
round((rollsumr(parts, 13) - parts) / 12)
##      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
## 2017   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
```